# Replace html span tag text with image

Tags: html, css, image, svg

I would like to change the text "*Confidențialitate & Cookie-uri*" to an image (to [this image](https://flexinstal.ro/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/cookies.svg)) using CSS in the following code:

```
 <div id="cookie-law-info-again" data-nosnippet="true" style="background-color: rgb(37, 166, 226); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: fixed; font-family: inherit; width: auto; bottom: 0px; left: 20px;">
  <span id="cookie_hdr_showagain">Confidențialitate &amp; Cookie-uri</span>
</div>
```

on my website: [link](https://www.flexinstal.ro/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, and tell me if it works:

```css
#cookie_hdr_showagain {
  background: url(https://flexinstal.ro/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/cookies.svg);
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: block;
  background-size: contain;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  font-size: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="cookie-law-info-again" data-nosnippet="true" style="background-color: rgb(37, 166, 226); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: fixed; font-family: inherit; width: auto; bottom: 0px; left: 20px;">
  <span id="cookie_hdr_showagain">Confidențialitate &amp; Cookie-uri</span>
</div>
```

Comment: This answer worked for me with minimal modification. I added the following code to hide the shadow and made the background transparent: ` div#cookie-law-info-again { background-color: transparent !important; box-shadow: none !important;}` Thank you

Answer (score 3):

CSS provides a mechanism to replace the contents of an element directly with an image using `content: url(...)` so:

```css
#cookie_hdr_showagain {
  content: url('https://flexinstal.ro/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/cookies.svg')
}
```

```html
<div id="cookie-law-info-again" data-nosnippet="true" style="background-color: rgb(37, 166, 226); color: rgb(255, 255, 255); position: fixed; font-family: inherit; width: auto; bottom: 0px; left: 20px;">
  <span id="cookie_hdr_showagain">Confidențialitate &amp; Cookie-uri</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
#cookie_hdr_showagain {
  background: url(https://flexinstal.ro/wp-content/uploads/2023/10/cookies.svg);
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: block;
  background-size: contain;
  font-size: 0px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cookie-law-info-again" data-nosnippet="true">
    <span id="cookie_hdr_showagain">Confidențialitate &amp; Cookie-uri</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).